# Compiler Errors when trying to install a button in android studio

Tags: java, button, android-studio, compiler-errors

I'm new to android studio and have just started developing my first app,
I have managed to compile the application previously, but have just tried adding code to a button in order to change across activities, I have looked around and cannot figure out why, but I get 8 compile errors when I try to run but cannot figure out why!

Here is my code:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

```
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

And here is the code that is throwing up the compiler errors:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.ben.learning.MESSAGE";

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
    btn.btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

```
{


    public void onClick (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent
            (MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}

    );
}
```

}
...And the errors:

Error:(60, 36) error:  expected
Error:(60, 37) error: illegal start of type
Error:(60, 40) error: ')' expected
Error:(60, 45) error: ';' expected
Error:(60, 46) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(64, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(64, 16) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(64, 35) error: ';' expected
Error:(70, 6) error: illegal start of type

Any insight would be great, I'm just going in circles trying to figure this out!

Cheers. :)

Comment: Can you post the class this code is in

Comment: I have edited to the post to include all the code.

Comment: Looks like you are defining this button outside of any method.

Comment: Sorted it out now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the location of the button code to the onCreate method to solve the errors.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override


        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent
                    (MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```